# Rails: How to use sum and multiple models to get the total order value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord

I would like to display `@amount_spent` and `@amount_received` by each user. I've already finished the first part with `@amount_spent = Reservation.where(user_id: @user.id).sum(:total)`

Now I would also like to display the `@amount_received`, since I use Stripe Connect.

I've tried something similar to:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@products = @user.products
@amount_received = @products.reservations.sum(:total)
```

But when I try to use `reservations` with `@products` I get an `#<Product::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f50b8709fa8>` error.

Is there a better way or another way, probably with scopes?

#### User Model:

```
has_many :products
has_many :reservations
```

#### Product Model:

```
has_many :reservations
```

#### Reservation Model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :product
```

Comment: Please, show us the model relationships or the related schema parts.

Comment: I added the model relations.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `@products.reservations` to get all the reservations, because `@products` is a relationship (a collection) and you can call `has_many` methods on a single object. Instead you need to use SQL `JOIN` (implemented in ActiveRecord `joins`) to get all the relevant reservations and the to sum their total:

```
@products.joins(:reservations).sum('reservations.total')
```

See more:

- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins
- https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins
- http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the exception is because `.reservations` can only be called upon a single product. Not on a collection of products. The following should work:

```
@amount_received = Reservation.where(product_id: @products).sum(:total)
```

Normally you would specify the column to select, but this defaults to the *id*. Meaning `.where(product_id: @products)` produces the same result as `.where(product_id: @products.select(:id))`.